# Woocommerce Advanced Search with Attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-search

I hope someone can help me with this.  I have a woocommerce site that all of my products have an attribute of a specific city.  I would like the main product search to have a text field and a drop down of the the cities so the results are only products with the relevant term in the specified city.

I cannot find anything on how to add the attribute drop down and make sure that this filter is part of the search query.  Help!

Update:

Found something useful by using taxonomies in a drop down menu on the searchform.php file:

```
            <?php
            function get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args){
            $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
            $optionname = "optionname";
            $emptyvalue= "";
            $output ="<select name='".$optionname."'><option selected='".$selected."' value='".$emptyvalue."'>Select a City</option>'";

            foreach($myterms as $term){
            $term_taxonomy=$term->pa_city; //CHANGE ME
            $term_slug=$term->slug;
            $term_name =$term->name;
            $link = $term_slug;
            $output .="<option name='".$link."' value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
            }
            $output .="</select>";
            return $output;
            }

            $taxonomies = array('pa_city'); // CHANGE ME
            $args = array('order'=>'ASC','hide_empty'=>true);
            echo get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args);

            ?>
```

Only problem is I cannot find where to pass the option name taxonomy in woocommerce.  This search does not appear to use search.php.  Does anyone know where I can pass this in woocommerce?

Comment: Start a [research within this results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=meta_value+search+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: Thank you, I am poking around this now!